# How to implement an automatic payment system?

Tags: php, html, payment

I was thinking how to build an automated system to pay users who got some credits on the website.

Let's make things simple: I have an user table with a field €CREDIT for each users.
How can I pay each month those users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paypal have a fairly simple API. It all depends what payment system you want to use. If Paypal isn't appropriate, we need more information.